# Фреймворк для web-приложения с lazy loading tree

Tags: java, веб-программирование, vaadin

Добрый день!

Нужен некий простой, удобный, бесплатный и многофункциональный фреймворк для создания web-приложения (далее приложение).

Изначально написал на jsp, все работало хорошо, но теперь приходится расширять функциональность: нужно реализовать авторизацию, treeview с динамически подгружаемыми данными, диаграмму ганте. (это все на первом этапе)

Писать на голом gwt не хотелось, рассмотрел несколько фреймворков и остановился на vaadin-е. Но у vaadin мало функционала: нету lazy loading tree нормальной, диаграмму ганте сложно прикрутить(есть парочка, но они не подходят), и вообще Vaadin Designer для IntelliJ IDEA еще не вышел.

Подскажите какие-нибудь фреймворки для реализации такой программы на java или же покажите что я не прав насчет ваадина.

Comment: Vaadin сырой. Пробовал. На gwt можно реализовать всё что угодно.

Comment: @Jenkamen Это понятно. щас почти все фреймворки - это обвертки на gwt. вопрос в том, есть ли нормальные или все же писать на gwt(

Comment: Vaadin подойдёт исключительно для админки какого-то сайта. Но не для юзеров которые заходят на сайт. Он тяжелый - раз, мало гибкости - два. Фиг оптимизуешь, мало что настроешь.